# How to retrieve random records from Oracle with dbms_random

Tags: sql, database, oracle, random

I am a beginner in sql and I was wondering if you could help me figure out how to retrieve random records from Oracle. I have the following query:

```
SELECT p.* from data p where p.id in 
(SELECT DISTINCT t.id   FROM DATA t, comment c, PTV ptv   
WHERE t.code not in ('x','y','Z') 
and t.id = c.id(+)   and ptv.code = t.code   and ptv.code = t.code   
and ptv.version = t.version  AND t.TASK_CODE != 'DRAFT')
```

How can i select X number of random records from the results returned by the above query? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You can simply do it by Join Func.

Comment: Unrelated, but: stop using implicit joins in the where clause *especially* for outer joins (the `(+)` operator). Use an explicit `JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` operator. Even Oracle recommends to stop using the `(+)` operator.

Comment: On a side note. @a_horse_with_no_name In fact, there is nothing wrong with using oracle native(not ANSI) join syntax, it's just a matter of personal preferences to some extent. Does ANSI join provide more clarity, easiness and allows you to write more portable statements? Yes. I personally do prefer ANSI join syntax to the traditional one for that. But at the end of the day ANSI syntax will be transformed to the traditional one by the optimizer, anyway.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov: You are right, there is nothing "wrong" using a 20year old syntax that has been superseeded with a newer standard. One advantage of the explicit `JOIN` operator is that you can't accidentally create a cross join just because you forget the join condition. Plus there are things you can't do with the `(+)` operator compared to the `LEFT JOIN` operator (as I said: Oracle recommends to not use `(+)` any more)

Comment: @Nicholas Krasnov not true. I was stated by Oracle that some newer optimizer constructs are usable only with new the syntax. (But on contrary - if I remember correctly - somewhere in some special case you can use only (+)).

Comment: Thank you for the comments, helps me understand the query better. This query was written 10 years ago I believe, I don't think I am allowed to modify the existing query but would certainly change the operator to ANSI for the new query with Random selection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "easy" way to get a random number is to use `dbms_random.value` or `dbms_random.random()` and `rownum`:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select x.*
from (select t.*
      from t
      order by dbms_random.value
     ) x
where rownum < 10;
```

I suspect there are better ways to write your query.  If you want suggestions on that front, write *another question*, include sample data, desired results, and describe what you want the query to do.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is `dbms.random` in order by? ORA-00904: "DBMS"."RANDOM": invalid identifier.

Answer (score 2):

Use `SAMPLE` clause:

`select * from data t SAMPLE(1) left outer join comment c on (t.id = c.id)`